# Limit User Access To Particular Group/Device , Alarms , Events , Measurements

Tags: cumulocity

I want a user to only access a specific device in a group and alarms , measurements , events , related to that only.Kindly check and respond.

Answer (score 1):

To limit acceess the access of a user to a group of devices, assign inventory roles to that user.

For more details, please see the Administration App user guide here: https://cumulocity.com/guides/users-guide/administration#inventory, see chapter "Assigning inventory roles to users".

Comment: Hi Stefan , I did the same and it seems to be not working. I have documented the same and I can share the document with screenshots.